# I want to send the selected radio input to the backend using onChange in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am using React.js to create the front end side of a web application that can control home appliances.

What I want to achieve is
With radio input,
I use onChange to change heat, cool, auto, off, etc. to temp_mode_val variable
I want to send temp_mode_val to the backend with axios Post

Issue is I can send temp_mode_val but it's empty...
I don't know why...

[image]

React.js

```
const DiscoverOffice = () => {
    
    const { entity_id } = useParams();
    
    const SetTemperatureMode = async(data) => {
      console.log("Body sent to server", {
      entity_id: entity_id, 
      operation_mode: temp_mode_val
    })
      await axios.post('xxx.com',
        {
          entity_id: entity_id, 
          operation_mode: temp_mode_val
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
          },
        })
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result.data);
          console.log(entity_id);
          console.log(val);
          console.log('Set Mode!');
          setVal(val);
          // getDevices();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          console.log(entity_id);
          console.log('Missed set Mode!');
        });
    }


    const [temp_mode_val, setTemperatureMode2] = useState('off');

    const HeatHandleChange = (e) => {
      setTemperatureMode2(e.target.value);
      SetTemperatureMode(e.target.value);
    }

return (
    

                              <div className="ic_schedule_label flex">
                                <input
                                  className="heat_mode_radio"
                                  type="radio"
                                  value="heat"
                                  onChange={HeatHandleChange}
                                  checked={temp_mode_val === 'heat'}
                                />
                                <p className="radio_text">Heat</p>
                              </div>
                              <div className="ic_schedule_label flex">
                                <input
                                  className="heat_mode_radio"
                                  type="radio"
                                  value="cool"
                                  onChange={() => HeatHandleChange('cool')}
                                  checked={temp_mode_val === 'cool'}
                                />
                                <p className="radio_text">Cool</p>
                              </div>
                              <div className="ic_schedule_label flex">
                                <input
                                  className="heat_mode_radio"
                                  type="radio"
                                  value="auto"
                                  onChange={() => HeatHandleChange('auto')}
                                  checked={temp_mode_val === 'auto'}
                                />
                                <p className="radio_text">Auto</p>
                              </div>
                              <div className="ic_schedule_label flex">
                                <input
                                  className="heat_mode_radio"
                                  type="radio"
                                  value="off"
                                  onChange={() => HeatHandleChange('off')}
                                  checked={temp_mode_val === 'off'}
                                />
                                <p className="radio_text">Off</p>
                              </div>

    
      );
}
export default DiscoverOffice;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `e.target.data` just use `e` Since you passing directly the value as the argument.

if you want to use `e.target.data` you wll have to pass the event to the nested method call.
ex:

```
onChange={(e) => HeatHandleChange(e)
```

This way you will get `e.target.value`

Comment: Thanks but still temp_mode_val in const SetTemperatureMode is Empty...

Comment: That is because SetTemperatureMode method call happens before temp_mode_val updates. In this case you can try calling the SetTemperatureMode  method inside an useEffect with temp_mode_val as the dependency or just pass the value as the parameter of your SetTemperatureMode method. But In case you decide to use useEffect hook make sure to handle the initial call of useEffect because useEffect will execute itself once before you update your dependency.
I would suggest you to look at this react doc for better understanding https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/adding-interactivity

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string to the function `HeatHandleChange`.
You could use the e variable directly, or pass the change event instead.

You should set the state before calling your function.

```
const HeatHandleChange = (e) => {
    SetTemperatureMode(e);
    setTemperatureMode2(e); 
}
```

You also could use the passed value instead of your state.

```
await axios.post('xxx.com',
        {
            entity_id: entity_id,
            operation_mode: data
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
            },
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result.data);
            console.log(entity_id);
            console.log(val);
            console.log('Set Mode!');
            setVal(val);
            // getDevices();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(entity_id);
            console.log('Missed set Mode!');
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but still temp_mode_val in const SetTemperatureMode is Empty...

Comment: You need to set the state before you call the "setTemperatureMode2" function. Or you could use the passed value instead the state inside your axios fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

```
onChange={() => HeatHandleChange('Heat')}
```

and this works.

```
const SetTemperatureMode = async(data) => {
  console.log("Body sent to server", {
  entity_id: entity_id, 
  operation_mode: data
})
  await axios.post('xxx.com',
    {
      entity_id: entity_id, 
      operation_mode: data
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
      },
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result.data);
      console.log(entity_id);
      // console.log(val);
      console.log('Set Mode!');
      setTemperatureMode2(result.data.attributes.climate.filter(c => c.entity_id === entity_id).map((item,i) =>  item.operation_mode
      )[0]);
      // setVal(val);
      getDevices();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(entity_id);
      console.log('Missed set Mode!');
      alert('Unable to set Mode!');
      getDevices();
    });
}
```